reading nested xml from file and using classes to store info
I have a project that has success criteria that is being stored in xml format, and then it gets compared with log data to determine if a build is successful.  The xml contents is currently like this, but unfortunately I can't loop through the contents to send to my parse log contents because the lists are anonymous types:
var results1 =
xmlDoc2.Descendants("build")
.SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
.Select(p => new
{
    buildMach = b.Element("BuildMachine").Value,
    p1 = p.Element("ProcessName").Value,
    startTimeHeader = p.Element("startTimeHeader").Value,
    conditions = p.Descendants("Condition")
        .Select(c => new
        {
            cName = (string)c.Attribute("name")?.Value,
            cValue = (string)c.Attribute("value")?.Value
        })
        .ToList(),
    successCriteria = p.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
        .Select(sc => new
        {
            f1 = (string)sc.Element("field")?.Value,
            c1 = (string)sc.Element("comparison")?.Value,
            v1 = (string)sc.Element("value")?.Value
        })
        .ToList()
})).ToList();

//send to parse log method but need to find better way to get lists so not anonymous...this doesn't work:
foreach (var currentItem in results1)
{
   //string parameters except the list parameters preceded by l_
   ParseLogFile1(codeFreezeTime, currentItem.startTimeHeader, currentItem.buildMach, currentItem.p1, l_currentItem.conditions, l_currentItem.successCriteria);
}

I have new classes to try and accomplish that, and I'm trying to figure out how to use them with the above.  I was looking at linq using classes, but I'm not clear on how to get my data from the xml to read into the named classes so I can then access it and send to my parse log method.
If you want to see what the xml looks like, please see xml in previous question etc.
Here's the class info I want to use:
SuccessCriterium.cs:
public class SuccessCriterium
{
   public SuccessCriterium()
      List<SuccessCriteria> successCriteria = new List<SuccessCriteria>();
}

SuccessCriteria.cs:
public class SuccessCriteria
{
    public SuccessCriteria()
    {
        string f1 = "";
        string c1 = "";
        string v1 = "";
    }
}

Condition.cs:
public class Condition
{
    public Condition()
    {
        string cName = "";
        string cValue = "";
    }
}

Conditions.cs:
public class Condition
{
    public Condition()
    {
        List<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>();
    }
}

public class ProcessValidationInfo
{
    public ProcessValidationInfo()
    {
        string codeFreezeTime = "";
        string startTimeHeader = "";
        string buildMach = "";
        string p1 = "";
        Conditions conditions = new Conditions();
        SuccessCriterium successCriterium = new SuccessCriterium();
    }
}

My question is how do I store the xml obtained from the LINQ in the classes so it's not anonymous when I loop through the results later to send the info to my method?

You need to do a couple of things to fix up your code.

Fix your classes to include actual property definitions. Your current class definitions have no actual properties, and the constructors just set and discard variables local to the constructor. Once the properties are defined, there is no particular need for an explicit constructor.
Change the ProcessValidationInfo class to use properties of type List<Condition> and List<SuccessCriteria> directly. You do not need separate wrapper classes for these lists.
Drop the now-unneeded SuccessCriterium and Conditions classes.
Replace the new { ... initializer-list ... } anonymous class constructors with explicity-typed constructors - new ProcessValidationInfo { ... initializer-list ... } and similar.
Add a line to populate codeFreezeTime. (This was missing from the earlier solution.)

The updated class definitions would be something like:
public class Condition
{
    public string cName { get; set; } = "";
    public string cValue { get; set; } = "";
}

public class SuccessCriteria
{
    public string f1 { get; set; } = "";
    public string c1 { get; set; } = "";
    public string v1 { get; set; } = "";
}

public class ProcessValidationInfo
{
    public string codeFreezeTime { get; set; } = "";
    public string startTimeHeader { get; set; } = "";
    public string buildMach { get; set; } = "";
    public string p1 { get; set; } = "";
    public List<Condition> conditionList { get; set; } = new List<Condition>();
    public List<SuccessCriteria> successCriteriaList { get; set; } = new List<SuccessCriteria>();
}

The default initializers of the (= 0; and = new List<xxx>()) are probably not needed and can be eliminated from the above, unless you have a specific need for them. Common coding conventions would normally name the properties with an initial cap, but I have left those names unchanged for now.
I did take the liberty of renaming the collection properties to conditionList and successCriteriaList.
The XML parsing logic would then just need to add the explicit class names to the new {...initializers...} expressions.
var results1 =
    xmlDoc2.Descendants("build")
    .SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
    .Select(p => new ProcessValidationInfo
    {
        codeFreezeTime = b.Parent.Element("codeFreezeTime").Value,
        buildMach = b.Element("BuildMachine").Value,
        p1 = p.Element("ProcessName").Value,
        startTimeHeader = p.Element("startTimeHeader").Value,
        conditionList = p.Descendants("Condition")
            .Select(c => new Condition
            {
                cName = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                cValue = c.Attribute("value").Value
            })
            .ToList(),
        successCriteriaList = p.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
            .Select(sc => new SuccessCriteria
            {
                f1 = sc.Element("field").Value,
                c1 = sc.Element("comparison").Value,
                v1 = sc.Element("value").Value
            })
            .ToList()
    })).ToList();

The results are now of type List<ProcessValidationInfo>.
Results (partial):
    {"codeFreezeTime":"19:00","startTimeHeader":"StartTime","buildMach":"mach46","p1":"ParseISLogStats","conditionList":[{"cName":"BuildProject","cValue":"KInstallerBuild"},{"cName":"BaseBuildArea","cValue":"D:\\R_Builds\\K\\v2.1\\nightly"}],"successCriteriaList":[{"f1":"Status","c1":"equal","v1":"Success"}]}

(Note that the above results are just a JSON serialization of each ProcessValidationInfo object, because that was a convenient way of dumping their values in the demo code,
You can also just send the entire ProcessValidationInfo object to your ParseLogFile1() method as a single parameter.
//send to parse log method:
foreach (var currentItem in results1)
{
   ParseLogFile1(currentItem);
}

// elsewhere
public void ParseLogFile1(ProcessValidationInfo item)
{
   // Here you can reference the properties as needed:
   //   item.codeFreezeTime
   //   item.buildMach
   //   item.p1
   //   item.startTimeHeader
   //   foreach (var condition in item.conditionList) { ... }
   //   foreach (var successCriteria in item.successCriteriaList) { ... }
}

See this .NET fiddle for a demo.

Thank you so much.  I really appreciate it.  I'm learning a lot with this project.

@divyang4481's answer is also worth a look. The relatively new C# record type is a convenient compact way of defining data-only classes. Also, divyang4481's solution uses property names that mirror the source XML element and attribute names. Using consistent naming is a good practice that you may wish to include in your final solution. I had avoided renaming things above, even though I would much rather see a property named ProcessName and Field over p1 and f1. Whoever comes along later to maintain this code (including your future self) will thank you.


your source xml have 2 issues which makes xml broken on line 226 and 240
where value=33 -> should be value="33", same value=8 should be value="8"
and you still did not fix it in provided link (!)

values of conditions file path contaons one back slash instead of 2 (one as escape char)

the best approach was to Serialize to json, and from json Deserialize to object.


P.S. it was an complexity to convert Condition/s so I had to implement custom  converter

void Main()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(File.ReadAllText("c:\\1\\file.xml"));
    string myJsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(doc.Root, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse).Dump();
}

public class Build
{
    public string BuildMachine { get; set; }
    public List<Process> Process { get; set; }
}

public class BuildVerification
{
    public string codeFreezeTime { get; set; }
    public List<Build> build { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(ConditionsConverter))]
public class Conditions
{
    public List<Condition> Condition { get; set; }
    public Conditions() { Condition = new List<Condition>(); }
    
}

public class Condition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Process
{
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public string startTimeHeader { get; set; }
    public Conditions Conditions { get; set; }
    public SuccessCriteria successCriteria { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public BuildVerification BuildVerification { get; set; }
}

public class SuccessCriteria
{
    [JsonProperty("field")]
    public string field { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("comparison")]
    public string comparison { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
    public SuccessCriteria() {}
}

class ConditionsConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Conditions);
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var lst = new Conditions();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName)
                    throw new FormatException("Expected a property name, got: " + reader.TokenType);
                string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
                reader.Read();
                if (propertyName == "Condition")
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
                    {
                        var item = JObject.Load(reader);
                        lst.Condition.Add(new Condition() { Name = item.GetValue("@name").ToString(), Value = item.GetValue("@value").ToString() });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        var values = new List<string>();
                        while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
                        {
                            if (reader.Value != null)
                                values.Add(reader.Value?.ToString());
                            reader.Read();
                        }
                        values.Chunk(4).ToList().ForEach(fe =>
                        {
                            lst.Condition.Add(new Condition() { Name = fe[1], Value = fe[3] });
                        });
                    }
                }
                reader.Read();
            }
        }
        return lst;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }
        var o = value as Conditions;

        JObject jo = new JObject();
        Type type = value.GetType();
        jo.Add("type", type.Name);

        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}

result


Thanks! I appreciate it.  It has seemed to process the 33/8 correctly without quotes with my old format.  I'll look closer at it when I test it with the new format.

use record type like this
public record SuccessCriteria(string Field, string Comparison, string Value);

public record Condition(string Name, string Value);

public record ProcessValidationInfo(string CodeFreezeTime, string StartTimeHeader, string BuildMachine, string ProcessName, List<Condition> Conditions, List<SuccessCriteria> SuccessCriteria);

var results = xmlDoc2.Descendants("build")
    .SelectMany(b => b.Descendants("Process")
        .Select(p => new ProcessValidationInfo
        {
            BuildMachine = b.Element("BuildMachine")?.Value,
            ProcessName = p.Element("ProcessName")?.Value,
            StartTimeHeader = p.Element("startTimeHeader")?.Value,
            Conditions = p.Descendants("Condition")
                .Select(c => new Condition
                {
                    Name = c.Attribute("name")?.Value,
                    Value = c.Attribute("value")?.Value
                })
                .ToList(),
            SuccessCriteria = p.Descendants("SuccessCriteria")
                .Select(sc => new SuccessCriteria
                {
                    Field = sc.Element("field")?.Value,
                    Comparison = sc.Element("comparison")?.Value,
                    Value = sc.Element("value")?.Value
                })
                .ToList()
        }));

foreach (var currentItem in results)
{
    ParseLogFile1(currentItem.CodeFreezeTime, currentItem.StartTimeHeader, currentItem.BuildMachine, currentItem.ProcessName, currentItem.Conditions, currentItem.SuccessCriteria);
}


Thank you.  I like the record type use.  Very interesting...never heard of that before.
